# Заменить символ в начале строки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Нужно реализовать следующее:
Заменять английскую E на YE, если E стоит в начале любого слова в строке или после a, o, i, e, u, y

Буду очень благодарен за пример регулярного выражения! Или объяснению тому, как с помощью preg_replace можно проверить каждую первую букву в каждом слове и заменить ее

Comment: Что пытались делать вы? Где код, где текст по которому искать? За вас вряд -и это будут делать.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Как то так на вскидку -

```
preg_replace("/(^|\s|a|o|i|e|u|y)([e|E])/", "$1Y$2", $string);
```

с учетом регистра.